# ui.datepicker popup is not opening - Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker, angular-ui

I am using angular ui.datepicker directive, but the code given in their website is not working for me, and I am not able to understand the reason. The datepicker popup is not opening when I click on the calendar button. I have gone through many stackoverflow links but it didn't seem to work for me.

Here is my code -

HTML-

```
<html ng-app="demo">
  <head>
     <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/textAngular.min.js"></script> 
     <script src="/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.min"></script> 
     <script src="/js/app.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
      <datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm"></datepicker>  
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
         <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
         </span>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

app.js -

```
var app = angular.module('demo',['textAngular','ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('demoCtrl',[ '$location','$scope','$http', '$window', function($location, $scope, $http, $window){

    $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();            

    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

}]);
```

Can anyone help me with this problem ? Thanks in advance

Comment: any error message from console window?

Comment: no.. No error message.. @Rebornix

Comment: Please share a [mcve] (I'm too lazy to put together one)

Comment: ok.. This is the fiddle .. https://jsfiddle.net/sajalsuraj/fx01Lz1k/ .. @TJ .. If you want you can go for plunker

Comment: @sajalsuraj actually, you haven't even created an angular module in that fiddle ._. then how is it supposed to work? see this https://jsfiddle.net/fx01Lz1k/1/

Comment: ok thanks for making correction in fiddle.. But I have created the module in my js file.. You can see in the question's code.. @TJ

Comment: @sajalsuraj Isn't it working in fiddle i shared..? You have to reproduce the issue in a demo so that we can help you. We can't come and debug your website...